# Using this() in code

Tags: c#

I am new to CSharp.I have seen "this()" in some code.My question is Suppose if i call

Paremeterized constructor ,am i invoking the paremeterless constructor forcefully?.But According to constructor construction ,i believe parameterless constructor will be executed first.Can you please explain this with simple example so that i can get exactly when should i call "this()".Thanks in advance.

```
 public OrderHeader() { }

 public OrderHeader(string Number, DateTime OrderDate, int ItemQty)
            : this()
        {

          // Initialization goes here ....
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default (for classes), there is an implicit :base(), so it is always chaining *something*. Adding :this() calls the parameterless constructor of the current type, and so on - sooner or later it will call down to a base constructor of some kind. Yes, the :this(...) or :base(...) happens **before** the constructor body.

In the example shown, adding :this() does no harm, but does nothing useful either. In more complex scenarios, :this(...) is commonly used to avoid duplicating constructor code - usually directing all constructors to the most parameterized version - for example:

```
public Foo() : this(27, "abc") {} // default values
public Foo(int x, string y) {...validation, assignment, etc...}
```

Comment: Most parametrized, you meant?

Answer (score 6):

Well, you should use `this()` if you want to call the parameterless constructor, it's as simple as that.

For example, if you have two constructors, where the parameterless initializes `Id` and the parameterfull also initializes `Name`, you should use `this`, so that you don't repeat yourself:

```
public Foo()
{
    Id = ComputeId();
}

public Foo(string name)
    : this()
{
    Name = name;
}
```

On the other hand, if the paramterfull constructor is a different way to initialize the `Id`, you don't have to call `this()`:

```
public Foo()
{
    Id = ComputeId();
}

public Foo(int id)
{
    Id = id;
}
```

This syntax is also not limited to the parameterless constructor, you can call any other constructor the same way:

```
public Foo(int id, string name)
    : this(id)
{
    Name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Parameterless constructor will not be executed first by default - compiler will use only the constructor you're invoking explicitly. If you need to invoke the parameterless constructor for some reason then use `this()`.

You can see the difference in the example below if you remove `this()`.

```
class Test
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Test()
    {
        x = 1;
    }

    public Test(int y) : this() // remove this() and x will stay 0
    {
        this.y = y;
    }


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var t = new Test(5);
        Console.WriteLine("x={0} y={1}", t.x, t.y);
    }
}
```

As was mentioned in another answer - the rule to invoke the parameterless constructor first applies to the `base()` keyword. If you don't provide which base constructor to invoke then the compiler will attempt to invoke the parameterless one.

Answer (score 0):

Constructor chaining!

The important part to remmember is the order in which chain is called.

```
public OrderHeader() { //Executed First
    _number = "";
    _orderDate = DateTime.Now();
}

public OrderHeader(string Number)
            : this()
        {
          _number = Number;
        }

public OrderHeader(string Number, DateTime OrderDate, int ItemQty)
            : this(Number)
        {

           _orderDate = OrderDate;
           _itemQty = ItemQty;
        }
```